# Buffer de computadores

Tags: c, memória

Já li em vários lugares sobre *buffers* e lá falam que é um lugar na memória para guardar valores temporários então  eles dão um exemplo assim em C:

```
char exemplo[10];
```

e falam que isso e um *buffer*, mas o vetor `exemplo` esta dentro da função `int main` então ele não seria alocado no *stack*?

Answer (score 6):

Mais do que "guardar valores temporários", a função de um *buffer* é agrupar em conjuntos dados que seriam muito pequenos para serem tratados individualmente. Quando um processo (normalmente uma comunicação) possui um *overhead* fixo para cada dado processado, quanto maior esse dado menor a significância do *overhead* em relação ao que o processo faz de útil.

Os melhores exemplos que posso dar se referem à comunicação, mas como estamos falando de C vou dar um exemplo da leitura de um arquivo no disco rígido. Digamos que por alguma razão qualquer você queira ler um arquivo caractere por caractere e fazer alguma operação relativamente demorada com cada um deles. O que acontece quando você pede pro computador ler um caractere do arquivo?

1. O disco rígido, se estiver parado, começa a rodar. Na maioria das vezes, ele já estará rodando;
2. Dependendo de onde o dado está em relação à cabeça de leitura, o disco pode rodar desde nada até uma revolução quase completa até chegar no caractere que você quer. Uma vez que ele chegou lá, ele copia o caractere pra memória;
3. Uma vez na memória, seu programa pode acessá-lo. Ele faz alguma coisa com ele, e pede o segundo caractere do arquivo;
4. Acontece que o disco não "freou" naquele caractere específico que você leu: ele continuou rodando, pois seria impraticável ele parar naquele ponto exato da última leitura (primeiro porque talvez seja fisicamente impossível, dada sua velocidade, segundo porque mesmo que seja possível isso iria gastar muita energia e/ou desgastar os materiais do disco, e terceiro porque pode ter outros programas executando no computador que podem estar esperando para também acessar os dados no disco);
5. A consequência é que o caractere que você quer ler agora, um depois do que você acabou de ler, já "ficou pra trás": o disco teria que dar uma volta completa até que a cabeça de leitura voltasse pro ponto que você quer ler, e seu programa iria executar tão lentamente quanto demora pro seu disco rígido rodar (e não numa velocidade mais proporcional ao *clock* do seu processador).

Qual a solução? Em vez de ler um único caractere do arquivo, você lê vários de uma vez, guardando-os numa área temporária na memória de modo a ler *dela* da próxima vez que você quiser outro caractere. Assim, enquanto o disco rígido está rodando ele já copia vários caracteres de uma vez pra memória - em uma única fração de rotação - e seu programa consome esses dados da memória com a latência relativa a essa mídia (e suas *caches*), e não com a latência relativa ao disco rígido.

O fato de estar na *stack* ou no *heap* é irrelevante [pra esse propósito], como [explicado por Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/57236/215). O que importa é que você pegou dados de algum lugar - o disco, um armazenamento externo, um *socket*... - e "enfileirou" esses dados na memória, para consumi-los na velocidade mais adequada para o seu uso particular, independentemente do melhor tratamento dos mesmos em sua origem. Da mesma forma, você pode usar um *buffer* para ir guardando os dados que você produz, e só enviá-los ao seu destino final quando os mesmos tiverem um volume suficiente para serem bem tratados pelo seu destino.

Answer (score 2):

[*Buffer*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_(ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) (o artigo não é dos mais elucidativos) é essencialmente um conceito abstrato. Não existe uma área da memória que seja um *buffer* porque qualquer área pode ser um. Você define o que é um *buffer*. Ele é apenas um conjunto de *bytes* que normalmente é armazenado em uma variável temporariamente.

Em C normalmente ele é organizado através de um *array* alocado em algum lugar da memória. Neste exemplo citado ele está alocado no *stack*, mas nada impede que ele seja alocado no *heap* também.

Nada impede de você chamar seu *buffer* de `exemplo` mas o mais comum é dar um nome que deixe claro que ele será usado como *buffer*, portanto o no0me da vari´vel poderia ser `buffer`. Não muda nada tecnicamente mas deixa a intenção mais clara, e isto é importante quando estamos codificando.

E claro que uma variável chamada `buffer` pode ser usada para outras coisas também, só é recomendado que não o faça por uma questão de organização.

Um *buffer* é utilizado para guardar qualquer informação que venha de algum lugar. Os detalhes de como isto será feito não diz respeito ao *buffer*. Ele só precisa estar alocado em algum lugar, e o programa vai definir onde, e ter o espaço suficiente para o que se deseja naquele momento.

Então, tecnicamente o *buffer* não existe, é só uma forma de nomenclatura para algo comum para ajudar melhor entendimento do que está fazendo.

Isto é válido pelo menos dentro do contexto de programação de softwares, especialmente em C e outras linguagens de alto nível.