# Como usar gets() no C++?

Tags: c++

Como usar `gets()` no `C++`, ao se pedir para o digitar e armazenar numa variável  tipo `char`?

Comment: [Não use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used), utilize `fgets`. **:)**

Comment: @leonardovIlarinhoe preciso incluir alguma biblioteca para usar gets()?

Comment: depende, se for pra ler um só caracter não precisa, mas se for para ler uma cadeia de caracteres tem de incluir a string.h, desculpe tinha retirado a resposta porque estava errada, consertei e a coloquei novamente

Comment: Nuca use `gets`!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Deve-se evitar usar o [`gets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/gets), pois não é feita nenhuma verificação da entrada de dados, ao usá-lo você presume que o usuário digitará uma quantidade inferior ou igual de caracteres alocados para o [*buffer*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57235/6454), ao fazer isto, o teu código poderá estar sujeito ao [estouro de *buffer*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115613/6454).

1. [*Buffer* de computadores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57235/6454)
2. [O que é o *buffer overflow*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115613/6454)

**Nota**: Essa função tornou-se obsoleta no C++*11* e removida do C++*14*.

Algumas alternativas são: [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgets), [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

O [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgets) que diferente do `gets`, permite estipular o limite de caracteres que serão lidos, mesmo que o valor recebido seja maior, deste modo impossibilitando o estouro de *buffer*. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LIMITE 10

int main(void) {
    char linha [LIMITE];
    puts("Digite alguma coisa: "); // Stack Overflow em Português!

    if (fgets(linha, sizeof(linha), stdin) != NULL) {
        printf("Voce digitou: %s\n", linha); // Stack Ove
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/BzlfBH)

Você também pode preferir usar a classe [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) ao invés de `char`, pois ela faz o gerenciamento de sua própria memória, que conforme for necessário, aloca mais memória de forma dinâmica. O `std::string` geralmente protege contra estouro de *buffer*, mas ainda há situações em que erros de programação podem levar ao estouro de *buffer*.

Exemplo com o [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
  std::string linha;

  std::cout << "Digite um valor: " << std::endl;
  std::getline (std::cin, linha);
  std::cout << "Voce digitou: " << linha << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/SUTSuT)

Se você preferir continuar usando `char`, você pode fazer assim:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char linha[10];

    std::cout << "Digite um valor: " << std::endl; // Stack Overflow em Portguês!
    std::cin.getline(linha, sizeof(linha));
    std::cout << linha << std::endl; // Stack Ove

    return 0;
}
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/Vs2Nd2)

Answer (score 4):

Evite utilizar gets. Para armazenar somente um char em C++ use o objeto de entrada padrão (cin).

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char ch;

    std::cout << "Digite um caractere: ";
    std::cin >> ch;

    std::cout << "Caractere: " << ch << std::endl;
}
```

Se querers armazenar vários chars (num formato de string) até um espaço ou enter também utilize o objeto de entrada padrão:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::string minhaString;

   std::cout << "Digite uma string: ";
   std::cin >> minhaString;

   std::cout << "String: " << minhaString << std::endl;
}
```

Caso queira ler strings com espaços faça:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::string minhaString;

   std::cout << "Digite uma string: ";
   getline(std::cin, minhaString);

   std::cout << "String: " << minhaString << std::endl;
}
```

mas, **se você realmente gosta do `gets`**, e quer utilizá-lo por capricho para somente ler um único char faça:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char ch[1];

   gets(ch);
   printf("Caractere: %c\n", *ch);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`gets` substitui o `scanf` ficaria assim:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
    char lista[100];
    printf("Digite seu nome: ");
    gets(lista);
    printf(lista);
}
```

Desculpe se errei algo, estou acostumado com C.

A função `gets` é mais usada para a criação de strings (cadeia de caracteres), assim se utiliza vetor para armazenar cada letra.

Para armazenar apenas um caractere é mais usado o `getchar` ou `fgetc`:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    char letra;
    printf("Digite uma letra: ");
    letra = getchar();
    printf("%c", letra);
}
```

Comment: -1 pelo gets e +1 pelo getchar = 0 rating :)

Comment: kk só dei um exemplo de como usar o gets, respondi a pergunta do gúri, sei também que usar gets não é a melhor opção

Comment: No último código, a variável `letra` tem de ter tipo `int`.