# Funcionamento do Request.Files;

Tags: c#, file-upload

Tenho um projeto Asp .Net MVC, com um formulário na *View* que envia arquivos para o *Controller*.

No controle recupero os arquivos da seguinte forma:

```
var myFiles = Request.Files;
```

Não salvo o arquivo, apenas leio o conteúdo.

A dúvida é: Onde estão esses arquivos do *`Request.Files`*? Na memória ou em alguma pasta temporária no servidor?

Imagine o seguinte cenário:

100 usuários enviando ao mesmo tempo 10 arquivos de 100MB cada, tudo isso será alocado na memória?

Acredito que isso pode prejudicar muito a performance do meu servidor, estou certo? Existe alguma forma de contornar o problema?

Comment: Limitar o upload?

Comment: Obrigado @LINQ , mas mesmo assim isso não limitaria a quantidade de usuários enviando simultaneamente uma pequena quantidade de arquivos. Ainda assim eu teria um problema, mas o que tem me causado dúvida é onde estão esses arquivos obtidos através do `Request.Files`, pois talvez eu pudesse pensar um pouco melhor com a resposta.

Comment: Bom, bem provável que eles fiquem na memória, junto com todas as outras informações sobre a _request_. Gravar em disco para recuperar depois me parece mais danoso do que ter isso em memória para fazer o que for preciso. Se você precisa de muitos uploads e que eles sejam de arquivos grandes, precisará de um servidor que aguente isto. Se tem medo de alguém fazer uma "brincadeira" e acabar atrapalhando o trabalho do servidor, precisará de uma forma de bloquear isso. De qualquer forma, eu não tenho certeza disso e não tenho como ver agora, é mais um palpite mesmo.

Comment: Obrigado mais uma vez @LINQ , também suponho que os arquivos estejam apenas na memória, mas eu gostaria de ter mais certeza disso. Estou tentando encontrar algo na documentação, mas sem sucesso por enquanto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo [essa documentação da Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.httppostedfile(v=vs.110).aspx) os arquivos **não** são salvos diretamente na memória do servidor (dependendo de alguns critérios).

> Files are uploaded in MIME multipart/form-data format. By default, all
>   requests, including form fields and uploaded files, larger than 256 KB
>   are buffered to disk, rather than held in server memory.
>
> **Tradução Livre:**
>   Os arquivos são carregados no formato MIME multipart/form-data. Por
>   padrão, todos os pedidos, incluindo campos de formulário e arquivos
>   carregados, maiores que 256 KB são armazenados em buffer no disco, em
>   vez de serem armazenados na memória do servidor.

Após o fim da solicitação, os arquivos carregados no servidor são destruídos, o que faz com que tenhamos de usar o método [SaveAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.saveas(v=vs.110).aspx) caso queiramos uma cópia durável em disco.

É possível especificar no *Web.config* algumas propriedades que alteram a quantidade de dados que serão armazenados em buffer, o [RequestLengthDiskThreshold](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestlengthdiskthreshold(v=vs.110).aspx), mas não se esqueça também do [MaxRequestLength](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength(v=vs.110).aspx) para evitar ataques de negação de serviços de alguns espertinhos que querem postar arquivos muito grandes.

[Mais sobre *Buffer*.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57235/buffer-de-computadores)